# how to move the slider according to value retrieved from database ? Jquery ui Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an option where the data is retrieved from the database and i need to position the slider according to the data retrieved.

For example

if the range is between 1 and 100 the retrieved data is 50 then the slider button should be in the center.

Here is the code i am using. I dont get the slider to point to value retrieved. Its showing at min value

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(function() {
        j$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({

            value: "{!avghoursperday}",// this is wat i am getting from salesforce DB
            min: 1,
            max: 100,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                j$( "#slider-range-min" ).next().val(ui.value );
            }
        });
        j$( "#slider-range-min" ).next().val(  j$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value"      )      );
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting the value parameter as a string?

```
value: "{!avghoursperday}"
```

I think it is expecting an integer

Comment: yup you are right... that really was the problem and since the range was high i was not able to verify the change had happened. Once i changed the max value to 30 then i could see the change in the slider position